# Why would the addition of an index in SQL Server slow a query, when that index is not used in the plan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, indexing

I am stumped. If I remove an index that is not used by the query, then the query goes from 46 seconds down to 6 seconds.

Here is the query:

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[alarm_class_id] AS [alarm_class_id], 
[Extent2].[domain_id] AS [domain_id], 
[Extent3].[description] AS [description], 
[Extent1].[list_id] AS [list_id], 
[Extent2].[list_source] AS [list_source], 
[Extent1].[list_detail_id] AS [list_detail_id], 
[Extent1].[plate] AS [plate], 
[Extent1].[notes] AS [notes], 
[Extent1].[locale_id] AS [locale_id], 
[Extent1].[end_date] AS [end_date], 
[Extent2].[eoc_list_id] AS [eoc_list_id], 
[Extent2].[list_type_id] AS [list_type_id]
FROM   [dbo].[list] AS [Extent2]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[ron_list_detail] AS [Extent1] ON [Extent1].[list_id] = [Extent2].[list_id]
INNER JOIN [dbo].[domain_lookup] AS [Extent3] ON [Extent2].[domain_id] = [Extent3].[domain_id]
WHERE ([Extent2].[domain_id] IN (7)) AND (([Extent1].[end_date] IS NULL) OR ([Extent1].[end_date] > (SysDateTimeOffset())))
```

Here is the index:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [ron_CI_list_detail-list_id-plate] 
ON [dbo].[ron_list_detail] ([list_id] ASC, [plate] ASC)
         WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
               SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, 
               ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 90) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Additional info: the query plan does not use this index unless I supply a hint.  If I supply the hint, the the query is within a second.

I am confused - thoughts? (would have shown the query plan, but I couldn't figure out how to paste the image)

Comment: I can think of arcane reasons.  For instance, because of the index, additional statistical information is available.  The information leads to a bad query plan, however.

Comment: All I can say is, "it happens". I have one specific query that I have to include a HINT on because if I don't, it runs 100 times slower. Unless I remove that index which is specifically designed to speed that specific query. The plan optimizer never selects the query on its own, and its presence seems to make it use a TERRIBLE plan. No idea why. It's just this one time and one situation. I think one in 999 times, it just doesn't work on its own, and needs to be hand-held. The only work around is to include the hint.

Comment: What happens if you create the index without [Plate], like this:

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [idx_Test] ON [dbo].[ron_list_detail]
(
    [list_id] ASC
)

Comment: @pmbAustin - you are describing my situation to the T

Comment: @MJH - thanks for the idea.  I tried it but no luck. I appreciate the thought!

Comment: Interesting, can you paste in the query plans (with and without the index)?

Comment: @MJH - please see my answer about TOP.  (And I am not sure how to paste an image)

Answer (score 3):

One of the reasons I can think of is outdated statistics on other indices. Here's how it might happen:

1. Your existing indices have outdated statistics that trick the optimiser to think they are better for your query. As a result, the new index isn't used;
2. When it comes to actual query execution, resulting plan misses by a lot and query takes a long time to run;
3. When you nail the index down with a hint, query optimiser has no choice but to use it, and it runs much faster (as it should be).

When optimising indices, make sure all of them are freshly rebuilt and all statistics are updated (not necessarily with `fullscan`, default mode usually works just as well). Most probably, after you execute something like

```
alter index all on [dbo].[ron_list_detail] rebuild;
```

the plan might straighten up without the need of any hints.

Another thing is that your index doesn't look optimal for this particular query. I would rather think of `domain_id, list_id`, because the `plate` column is only returned as the output and isn't used in any of the join conditions.

Comment: thanks for the info.  Turns out it my problem closely resembles the comment left by pmbAustin.   It will run quicker (6 seconds) without any indexes at all. With the hint - it will be under a second.  With the index and no hint, then it is 48 seconds

Comment: @RonIsaac, so you didn't try to rebuild indices, then?

Comment: Sorry I missed specifying that.  We did rebuild the indexes. It did not help.  Turns out it is the inclusion of Top which creates the bad plan.  No Top or Top >=1192, then it runs fine; small TOP (<=1191) and it runs slow.  Go figure

Comment: @RonIsaac, yes, I've seen situations like that. Have you tried the index I suggested? Or better yet, with different order of columns - `domain_id, list_id` - It should be better for your query.

Comment: 18  - We need the indexes as they are for other areas (sorry I should have stated that as part of the problem - just read 'how to post a question') - We will solve by using a view with a hint. The view will be accessed by Entity Framework (which is why we will use a view. Entity Framework won't allow hints)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it is the TOP in the query.

SELECT ... is fast
SELECT TOP (1191) ... is slow
SELECT TOP (1192) .... is fast

any number <= 1191 is slow
any number >= 1192 is fast
No Top at all is fast

weird!!!